# Automatically change data in query API with Python using requests

Tags: python, date, python-requests

I'm using an API to get some date (see code below) and everything works fine so far.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
query = """
query Dataset 
{
    elspotprices
    (
        where:
        {
            HourUTC: {_gt: \"2021-09-30\"}
            PriceArea: {_eq: \"DK2\"}
        }
        order_by: 
        {
            HourUTC: asc
        } 
        offset:0
    )
    {   
        SpotPriceDKK
    }
}
"""
request = requests.post('https://data-api.energidataservice.dk/v1/graphql', json={"query":query}, headers=headers)
data = request.json()['data']['elspotprices']
spotprices_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

However, I would like to define my variable **date** that represents any day and automatically change also the query string (an example of code is shown below which **doesn't work**) where the HourUTC is specified.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

date = "2021-09-30\"

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
query = """
query Dataset 
{
    elspotprices
    (
        where:
        {
            HourUTC: {_gt: \date}
            PriceArea: {_eq: \"DK2\"}
        }
        order_by: 
        {
            HourUTC: asc
        } 
        offset:0
    )
    {   
        SpotPriceDKK
    }
}
"""
request = requests.post('https://data-api.energidataservice.dk/v1/graphql', json={"query":query}, headers=headers)
data = request.json()['data']['elspotprices']
spotprices_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Unfortunately, I didn't find the right way to do it yet but I'm pretty sure that there should be a way to do it.